# Dynamodb single table structure for Many to many relation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have two Entity Categories and Users. It is classic many 2 many relations.

1. Users can be tagged to multiple category
2. Category can have multiple users

Access patterns

1. Get list of categories
2. Get list of users, with categories users belong to
3. Get single user, with categories single user belong to
4. Get List of users in specific category

I tried to model using Adjacency pattern
[image: table]
[image: adjacency]
[image: type index]

but I have few confusions on how to query for

1. Users list and also get all categories each users belong to

Answer (score 2):

If you have a PK containing the Category and an SK containing the User to model the users in each category, you can create a Global Secondary Index (GSI) with the PK pointing to the original table‘s SK (User) and the SK pointing to the original table’s PK (Category).

```
Table
| PK  | SK  | ...
| C#1 | U#1 | ...
| C#1 | U#2 | ...
| C#2 | U#1 | ...
| C#2 | U#3 | ...

GSI
| Table_SK | Table_PK | ...
| U#1      | C#1      | ...
| U#1      | C#2      | ...
| U#2      | C#1      | ...
| U#3      | C#2      | ...
```

Now you can query:

- All categories including their respective users (scan Table)
- All users in a single category (query Table)
- All users including their respective categories (scan GSI)
- All categories that a single user belongs to (query GSI)

**Update: Extended model to include metadata as per comments**

```
Table
| PK  | SK   | CAT | USR | Metadata
 ---------------------------------------
|     | DATA |           | { ...: ... } 
| C#1 | U#1  | C#1 | U#1 | { ...: ... } (copied from user record)
|     | U#2  | C#1 | U#1 | { ...: ... } (copied from user record)
 ---------------------------------------
|     | DATA |           | { ...: ... }
| C#2 | U#1  | C#1 | U#1 | { ...: ... } (copied from user record)
|     | U#3  | C#1 | U#1 | { ...: ... } (copied from user record)
 ---------------------------------------
| U#1 | DATA |           | { ...: ... }
 ---------------------------------------
| U#2 | DATA |           | { ...: ... }
 ---------------------------------------
| U#3 | DATA |           | { ...: ... }
 ---------------------------------------

GSI_Users
| Table_USR | Table_CAT |
 -----------------------
| U#1       | C#1       |
|           | C#2       |
 -----------------------
| U#2       | C#1       |
 -----------------------
| U#3       | C#2       |
 -----------------------

GSI_Categories
| Table_CAT | Table_USR |
 -----------------------
| C#1       | U#1       |
|           | U#2       |
 -----------------------
| C#2       | U#1       |
|           | U#3       |
 -----------------------
```

Queries:

- All Categories (incl their Users): Scan GSI_Categories
- All Users (including their Categories): Scan GSI_Users
- Specific Category (including metadata): Query Table by `C#x` and `SK=DATA`
- Specific Category and its Users: Query GSI_Categories by `C#x`
- Specific User (including metadata): Query Table by `U#x` and `SK=DATA`
- Sepcific User and its Categories: Query GSI_Users by `U#x`

Comment: What about the Category meta data and user meta data?

Comment: Metadata can still be modeled in separate rows as part of the main table.

Comment: To not copy metadata to the GSI you can introduce separate attributes to be used for the GSI. I'll add an extended model in the answer, give me a second.

Comment: Is my model correct, I added in the screenshots from NoSql workbench

Comment: I don't know if your model is correct because it contains a lot of information that is not part of your question. One way to model the many-to-many relationship without having metadata pollute the GSIs is what I've sketched out in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the updated model, with this model is it possible to get users meta data when we query for specific category to get list of users in any specific category.

Comment: Hm, sorry. Right now I'm not able to come up with a model that would solve that case out of the box. But at some point every model reaches its limitations and to not overcomplicate it too much, I'd rather copy the user's metedata whenever a user is being added to a category.

Comment: no problem so basically we can duplicate meta data where required to overcome the limitations?

Comment: Sure. Data duplication is not a bad thing, as long as you make sure it stays consistent. So updating a user’s metadata should automatically kick off a process that updates the copies. This can be done asynchronously, though, by having a function subscribe to the DynamoDB table‘s stream.

Comment: One issue i see with data duplication is if I ever need to change name of categories, we will need to update all records where we have duplicated category name right